# Selenium (Geb) shows blank page and fails sometimes

Tags: java, selenium, geb

Could you please advise, I'm working on integration tests using Gebish(Selenium) library. 
I have several steps in my tests and two scenarios. Before each scenario I create 'browser' object, and after each I call 'browser.quit()'.

I actively use waitFor constructions, so that I give some time for updates from mouse actions become available.

The problem is that **sometimes** without any obvious reasons tests fail, usually just only one of the last steps fails. Other previous are passed. But if this fail happens I see **very** strange situation: at the beginning I see the first new FF window for the first scenario, but it is empty, after that I see next FF window for another scenario, it is empty too.

So as a result - I got one failed test cases and a lot of passed and I have **two** instances of FF with blank pages which were not closed automatically.

I'm very confused. I tried to use different timeouts in waitFor constructions, I tried ChromeDriver instead of FFdriver, and I still have the same problem with the same scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at the cmd window for clues.
It shows a blank page when the server reached its maximum instance of a browser, so maybe that is the problem. Check the cmd window when you create a browser object and see if it gives an error. If this is your problem, close the cmd window and reopen your server.